# Extending a Generic Class and Overriding a Method in Haxe in IntelliJ

Tags: generics, intellij-idea, haxe

I'm re-learning Haxe and HaxeFlixel as I go, but I've hit a stumbling block when it comes to generics.

I have a generic super class with (among other things) a method that both takes and returns a generic argument `T`. In a particular subclass of that super class, I would like to override that method to slightly augment it's behaviour. In Java this is no problem, as such:

```
public class A<T> {
  public T doStuff(T t) {
    return t;
  }
}

public class B extends A<String> {
  public String doStuff(String s) {
    System.out.println(s)
      return s;
   }
}
```

This compiles and functions correctly. However when I try to do essentially the same thing in Haxe:

```
class A<T> {
  public function doStuff(t : T) : T {
    return t;
  }
}

class B extends A<String> {
  public override function doStuff(s : String) : String { //Compilation error
    trace(s);
    return s;
  }
}
```

IntelliJ shows an error on the marked line both on the arg type and the return type, with the messages

> Type String is not compatible with T

and

> Not compatible with return type String != T

However, it does compile anyways. Is my Haxe setup within IntelliJ incorrect, or is this a bug in the Haxe Support?

Comment: Don't know Haxe, but [doc](https://haxe.org/manual/types-basic-types.html) says *"Basic types are `Bool`, `Float` and `Int`. [...] **Basic types are not classes** in Haxe."* It would seem that `T` cannot be a *basic type*, similar to how `T` cannot be a Java *primitive* (e.g. `int`).

Comment: This is only an MVC, my real example is with a different (non-simple) class; same issue. I'll edit it so that simple/non-simple types shouldn't matter

Comment: Your sample compiles fine on dynamic target, are you compiling on static (cpp)? which version of haxe are you using? http://try.haxe.org/#6E8c9

Comment: Compiles fine on a static too, im guessing that there is another line that causes an error.

Comment: @MihailIgnatiev thanks for double checking, because you're right, it does compile. My question now (see update) is why intelliJ is still flagging it as an error when it does compile

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine. It's a bug in the IntelliJ plugin.

IMHO, you could try to work with another IDE, that's not the best one for now (for Haxe), and if you check the repository, it's not maintained anymore.
You could try [HaxeDevelop](http://www.haxedevelop.org/) (Windows) or [VSCode](https://github.com/vshaxe/vshaxe) (Windows/Linux/Mac).